# How to know API key for using google map in android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

The new layout of google console(https://console.developers.google.com/
) is little bit difficult to understand.
Where is API access and how can I get the API key and how can I sign the authentication etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `APIs & Auth` -> `Credentials`, you click `Add Credentials` to add one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create **new project** from the top left option i.e. dropdown given in the link. After creating new project, you will be able to find the options such as APIS, Permissions, etc. in the left panel. You need to enable **Google Maps Android API** under **Google Maps API** section. After doing that navigate to **credentials** section and click on **Add credentials**, on selecting **API key**, you will be asked to choose type of the keys. Select **Android Key** and on providing **package name** and **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** you will be able to get the API key for your app.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to the https://console.developers.google.com/
2. create one project
3. enabled the google map api
4. Click API&AUTH Menu and click credential sub menu
5. Click and credentials and select the android key
6. set your app package and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.
7. Now generate the google map API Key

Thanks